# Adding a 'Date Modified' column that will populate the date the .csv is appended

Tags: powershell, append, export-csv

I am exporting an array of data to a .csv file when my script detects a certain condition for a device and then deletes the device from the console. The .csv is a record of the deleted device info, and I'm using Export-Csv with the -append command to add a line every time this happens, and I'd like to have the script add a date column when this action happens, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this. 
The .csv file currently has columns for strings in the array, like 'owner', 'model', 'phone number', etc.

I have tried many options I've found via Internet searches, but nothing seems to be working.

```
Foreach ($item in $noncomp60){

    $nc60details += $noncomp | ? {$_.Serial -eq $item}
    $nc60details | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Append
```

I'd like the .csv file to have an addition column titled 'Date Deleted' which is populated when the .csv is appended.

Comment: You can use `$currentObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'Date Deleted' -Value your_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line before `Export-Csv`

```
$nc60details | Add-Member -Name 'DateDeleted' -Value (get-date) -MemberType NoteProperty
```

Comment: I have tried adding that line, however, I saw nothing different in the spreadsheet. The column wasn't created, nor did a date get entered. The new line of data did get entered.  Please confirm line looks accurate: `$nc60details | Add-Member -Name 'DateDeleted' -Value (get-date) -MemberType NoteProperty | Export-Csv -Path $path -NoTypeInformation -Append`

Comment: My apologies, when using the **| Add-Member** code, a new line is NOT appended to the sheet, so the code fully stops working.

Comment: Nevermind, it did work when I added to the line _before_, like suggested. I also had to create a header in the .csv file with that same name (DateDeleted), but it then populated. You all are great!